# delete php mysql doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

This code is making me sick

this is the result:

[image]

and here comes the code:

```
   <?php        
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
mysql_select_db('mybd', $conexion);   
$consulta_mysql='select * from agenda';
$resultado_consulta_mysql=mysql_query($consulta_mysql,$conexion);
  echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
  echo "<select name='id'>";
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)){

    echo "<option value='".$fila['id']."' >".$fila['id']." ".$fila['nombre']."</option>";
 }
    echo "</select><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='borrar'";
    echo "</form> <br>";

  if (isset($_POST['id'])){
   $id = $_POST['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("mybd",$link);
  $sql = "DELETE from prueba.agenda WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
  echo "&#33;Hemos eliminado los datos selecionados&#161";
 }
    //doesnt enter into the if
  else {it doesnt enter
 echo "no entro en el aif";}

 ?>
```

I'm a little newbie sorry :/

Comment: [`mysql_` functions are officially deprecated](http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases).

Comment: what is the error? what have you tried? which line is throwing the error?

Comment: If the code is making you sick, correct code formatting would be the first step to cure you.

Comment: SQL injection alert !

Comment: @Harry , I run it and it doesnt enter into the if. U can see the result here http://i.imgur.com/CjEJXJ2.png

Comment: @AndréDaniel I dont care about security because is an exercice for class :\

Comment: When you first load the page, it doesn't go into the `if` because you haven't submitted the form yet. When you select something and submit, it should go into the `if`.

Comment: I FINALLY FOUND THE ERROR i forget to put > in



     echo "<input type='submit' value='borrar'";

Newbie programmer's facts T.T

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code:

```
<?php        
$conexion = mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
mysql_select_db('mybd', $conexion);   
$consulta_mysql='select * from agenda';
$resultado_consulta_mysql=mysql_query($consulta_mysql,$conexion);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="id">
<?php
while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_consulta_mysql)) {

    echo "<option value='".$fila['id']."' >"
         .$fila['id']." ".$fila['nombre']."</option>";
}
?>
    </select><br>
    <input type='submit' value='borrar'>
</form> <br>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("mybd",$link);
    $sql = "DELETE from prueba.agenda WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "&#33;Hemos eliminado los datos selecionados&#161";
} else {
    //doesnt enter into the if
    echo "no entro en el aif";
}
?>
```

Well if it's going into the else statement, it means that $_POST['id'] hasn't been set, meaning you're either not posting to this page or you're not posting `id` to this page. This could be a problem with the HTML. I noticed your `<input type='submit' value='borrar'>` didn't have a `>` meaning the HTML could've been messing up and causing this.

Sometimes bugs can be little mistakes in typing or forgetting to do something.

Additional notes:

1. `mysql_` functions are deprecated, so you should consider using `mysqli_` or `PDO`
   Personally I'd recommend `PDO`
2. Not only is my first point relevant, but your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. What is SQL inject? It's when a users input isn't sanitized and the variable for it is directly placed in the SQL. Why is this bad? It allows users to put SQL in their input and actually modify the SQL code running, which in turn can give them access to get information you wouldn't want them to get, and possibly do worse.
3. Formatting your code to a more "readable" standard helps others read your code. There are "standards" for laying out your code, and while many wont stick to these standards to the letter, it's best to keep as close to them as possible.

Answer (score 0):

using this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = "DELETE from prueba.agenda WHERE id=$id";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
  echo "&#33;Hemos eliminado los datos selecionados&#161";
 }
    //doesnt enter into the if
  else {it doesnt enter
 echo "no entro en el aif";}

 ?>
```

your code in this line use name = submit, change the $_POST['id'] to $_POST['submit']

```
"<input type='submit'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $id = "" ;
if (isset($_GET['id'])){

    $id = trim(strip_tags($_GET['id']));

}

  if (!empty($id)) {
      if(mysql_query("DELETE FROM prueba.agenda WHERE id='$id'")){

          if(TRUE){
            ?><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=yourURL.php?teade=good"><?php
          }  else{
              ?><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=yourURL.php?teade=bad"><?php
             }

       }

  }
```

Try something like this ;)

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM prueba.agenda WHERE id = '$id' " ;

Comment: just incase add this too ;)